# How to call one war file urls in another war file web.xml in java

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-dispatching

I am new to java development. In my project i have multiple `.ear` files with `war` files. For example i have `first.ear` have `config.war` and `transactions.war`, and  `second.ear` have `employee.war`,`server.war` and `webconfig.war` files.

Now my requirement is `config.war` and `transactions.war` file have some URLs, that `URLs` i want to access inside of `webconfig` project `web.xml` file by using filters or any other.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: This question is about very basic servlet functionality.  For questions at this level, I'd start one of many servlet tutorials, with a focus on request forwarding and servlet filters.)

This may provide an answer:

[Forward a servlet request to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860569/forward-a-servlet-request-to-another-server)

For a very detailed design pattern perspective, try:

[Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)

This introduces servlet filters:

[Difference between request dispatcher forward and servlet chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844481/difference-between-request-dispatcher-forward-and-servlet-chaining)

This provides some practical examples:

[How to use a servlet filter in Java to change an incoming servlet request url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url)